# prime ideals of polynomial rings over a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $(R,\ m)$ be a local commutative ring with identity,  and $R[x]$ be the polynomial ring over $R$. Is the following true?

> The prime ideals of $R[x]$  above $m$ are of the following form:
>   1. $mR[x]$ and
>   2. $\langle m, q\rangle R[x]$ for each polynomial $q\in R[x]$ which is irreducible modulo $m$.

If it is true, is there any proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prime ideals of $R[x]$ above $m$ correspond to the prime ideals of $S=R[x]/mR[x]$. The ring $S\cong k[x]$ where $k=R/m$. The prime ideals of a polynomial ring over a field are the zero ideal, and the ideals generated by
irreducibles.

So the prime ideals of $R[x]$ above $m$ are $mR[x]$ and $mR[x]+\left <f\right>$ where $f$ is irreducible modulo $m$.